# Is it possible to .gitignore only certain .css files that are build products of neighboring .less/.scss files?

Tags: css, sass, less, gitignore, create-react-app

I'm working on a Create-React-App project, which notoriously does not support css transpilers such as SASS and Less. The general solution, as discussed [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc) and [here](https://hackernoon.com/using-sass-with-create-react-app-without-ejecting-b5f4f827ed9e), is to compile the source .less/.scss and import the build product .css into your components. Then you can remove all .css from source control and only track .less/.scss.

This is a fine solution, but only a handful of my components really need Less for clarity/extensibility; for the most part, pure css is fine. So, what I'd like to do is use .css everywhere except for some .less sprinkled in here and there. I can configure this with the Less compiler, but for source control I'd like to watch only the "source" css files, and ignore the "build" css files (generated from Less). Because of this I cannot blanket .gitignore all .css, since some are truly source files.

So, **is there a glob pattern for this?** Maybe:

```
*.css where *.less
```

I see two other possible solutions:

1. switch everything to .less, even when it's not necessary, and go on ignoring all *.css
2. selectively .gitignore only the .css that are build products.

I like option 2, but it just seems a little error prone and more maintenance.

Comment: you can create a simple file reader that looks for .less files and append them in your .gitignore after replacing src/*.less to build/*.css. and run this task so any new .less files are found that will also be added to your .gitignore file

Answer (score 0):

Switch everything to less is the verter choice: only one why to make css. It is also easiest to understand how project works for a colleague.

You should also keep different css folders for generated and non generated css file. Then, you can just ignore folder with generated.

Answer (score 0):

You could get 2 folders for exemple `src` and `dist`

Simply put source .css and .less files in the `src` folder and when compiling this folder, copy the .css files to the `dist` one while .less files are compiled.

But I prefer your "all .less" approach which is less confusing for other developpers.